# I can not image uploads in php

Tags: php, file-upload

```
if(!empty($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"])){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], BASE.'/uploads/thumbs/'.$_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
    $a['foto'] = '../uploads/thumbs/'.$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

}
```

It seems that $ _FILES ['foto'] ['tmp'] is not returning any value ...

Comment: Where is the code of your form or your request?

Comment: 9 times out of 10, this is because you don't have `<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>` Post your form code. ( the 10th time, by the way, is often because the `name=` attribute is missing from the file input )